# error calling startservicebyname for org.xfce.filemanager: timeout reached

Tags: xubuntu, 19.04, filemanager

Afternoon all. 
Sometimes when I boot up Xubuntu 19.04, Thunar fails to start with the error:

`error calling startservicebyname for org.xfce.filemanager:  timeout reached`

I need help diagnosing the problem, and resolving it it please as I cannot start thunar manually when this happens.

Cheers.

**Edit**

Outputs requested by @N0rbert

```
apt-cache policy thunar thunar-data
```

```
thunar:
  Installed: 1.8.9-1
  Candidate: 1.8.9-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.8.9-1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
thunar-data:
  Installed: 1.8.9-1
  Candidate: 1.8.9-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.8.9-1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

And

```
thunar
```

```
Failed to register: Timeout was reached
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy thunar thunar-data` and `thunar` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1199152/edit).

Comment: Hello everyone. Still have this issue -- though it is intermittent.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem under XUbuntu 19.10.
My solution was to uninstall the "thunar-archive-plugin".
These files are affected:

```
thunar-archive-plugin 0.4.0-2
thunar 1.8.9-1
thunar-data 1.8.9-1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was emanating from smb through gvfs-daemon

```
Feb 18 22:31:21 akash-x230 systemd[960]: Starting gvfs-daemon.service - Virtual filesystem service...
Feb 18 22:31:21 akash-x230 systemd[960]: Started gvfs-daemon.service - Virtual filesystem service.
Feb 19 14:12:09 akash-x230 gvfsd[20609]: smbXcli_negprot_smb1_done: No compatible protocol selected by server.
Feb 19 14:12:09 akash-x230 gvfsd[20609]: got no contact to IPC$
Feb 19 14:12:09 akash-x230 gvfsd[20609]: smbXcli_negprot_smb1_done: No compatible protocol selected by server.
Feb 19 14:12:09 akash-x230 gvfsd[20609]: got no contact to IPC$
```

so `systemctl --user restart gvfs-daemon.service` fixed the indefinite timeout Thunar was experiencing -- restarting Thunar.service directly did not help.